# How to pass an environement variable to spark-defaults.conf

Tags: docker, apache-spark, environment-variables, config, spark-ui

I want to run apache spark history on a docker image, to achieve this I had to change spark-defaults.conf and add this line

```
spark.history.fs.logDirectory /path/to/remote/logs
```

And then run start-history-server.sh

This work fine when I set the value statically, however I want the value to be set from an environement variable that will be set on the docker container on run time, so I want something like this:

```
spark.history.fs.logDirectory ${env.path_to_logs}
```

However this doesn't work since the spark-defaults.conf deosn't access env variable, so is there a solution for this or maybe add a parameter when running start-history-server.sh ?

Comment: values inside spark-env.sh override value of spark-defaults.conf, this if you manage to change spark-env.shfrom env variable it should work